# How can I Disable HTML when a user forward my newsletter?

Tags: html, email, newsletter

i am sending a custome made newsletter in HTML for some event. When i forward newsletter from my email inbox, I am able to edit the content. Is there any way that I can use to disbale the HTML so that a user cannot make any change while forwarding it.

Comment: You can't. Email clients universally do not support any scripting from email.

Answer (score 0):

Only method is to use a giant image instead of html, but that is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is better to let your [HTML Newsletter](http://www.hirewordpressdeveloper.org/html-newsletter) that way to avoid more problem while sending them to your clients. You can also ask for a professional's help if you really want to disable HTML in forwarding your newsletter.